# Escaping spaces in prefix argument in the boto3's list_objects method

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using boto3.resource to get a list of objects from S3. I have a prefix string that looks something like

```
root/VIS/THING BAR/0/
```

This is sent up as

```
root/VIS/THING%5C+BAR/0/
```

Escaping the space with a `\\` dosen't help, it just transforms the spaces into a `+`

How do I escape the space so it gets sent up as a space instead of being transformed into a `%5C+` or a `+`?

Comment: Had you tried using `repr`?

Comment: What is "repr".

Comment: Its a function repr : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/repr

Comment: Yup, just tried it like this "repr("root/VIS/THING BAR/0/")". It replaced the spaces with a + :(

Comment: Could you please show us your actual code that is having a problem so that we can try to reproduce your issue? We will then be more likely to be able to offer a solution. Feel free to Edit your question to add more information.